# Store array globally in struct or other method

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, struct, global

I have an array of struct elements that I would like to store globally so that I can access it in different classes without having to run the query that populates it over and over.

I have a struct:

```
struct collectionStruct {
    var name : String
    var description : String
    var title : String
    var image : PFFile
    var id: String
}
```

and a variable:

```
var collectionArray = [collectionStruct]()
```

and some code to build the array:

```
for object in items {

                let arrayName = object.object(forKey: fromName) as! String
                let arrayDescription = object.object(forKey: fromDescription) as! String
                let arrayTitle = object.object(forKey: fromTitle) as! String
                let arrayImage = object.object(forKey: fromImage) as! PFFile
                let arrayID = object.objectId as String!

                collectionArray.append(collectionStruct(name: arrayName,
                                                            description: arrayDescription,
                                                                title: arrayTitle,
                                                                    image: arrayImage,
                                                                        id: arrayID!))
            }
```

I was thinking of creating another struct to hold the array itself bt am a bit lost here.  this is what I was thinking:

```
struct globalArray {

var collectionArray = [collectionStruct]()

}
```

but a probably way off

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should consider naming your struct CollectionStruct rather than collectionStruct - as that indicates it is a type. To access the array anywhere you could create a singleton. With a singleton, you ensure there is only one instance available by giving it a private constructor. Here is an example:

```
class Global {
    private init() { }
    static let sharedInstance = Global()
    var collection = [CollectionStruct]()
}
```

To use it you would use the following:

```
Global.sharedInstance.collection
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use singleton for global class that's able to be accessing from anywhere:

```
class GlobalArray {
   static let shared = GlobalArray()
   var collectionArray = [collectionStruct]()
}
```

and accessing like this to assign or read value:

`GlobalArray.shared.collectionArray`

Answer (score 2):

You can just declare

```
var collectionArray = [collectionStruct]()
```

at the top level in any file (outside any object), and it will be available globally

e.g.

```
var collectionArray = [collectionStruct]()

class MyClass {
    func printArray() {
        print(collectionArray)
    }
}
```

Comment: that will do thanks.  i was trying to make it hard for myself.